# Merge FLA files or Loading a swf file on another swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader, cs3

I have two FLA files, call them MAP.fla and ANI.fla, that I have to merge. One way I tried was to load the ANI.swf in MAP.swf during runtime using the normal way of doing it, using Loader and URLRequest. However, when I try to run it, flash detects errors about methods I have included in ANI.swf.

I do know that the Loader and URLRequest method of doing it works because I tried using it with a different SWF file with simpler content.

P.S. ANI.swf contains methods, instances with classes of their own and timer events. If Loader cannot work on my SWF, is there any other way of carefully doing this without affecing my FLAs?

Below is the error message i am getting. Thanks. :)

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at stageRotation/stageRotation::pause()
    at stageRotation/::create()
    at stageRotation/::initStage()
    at stageRotation$iinit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Loader and URLRequest, are the best ways for doing this work.

your problem may causes by an illegal (unsafe) refering to "stage", from ANI.SWF, or calling ANI.SWF functions from MAP.SWF but in a wrong way.

Can you attach that error message?

Comment: Edit: I have attached the error message above. Please see my edits. Thanks.

Comment: it seems that "stageRotation" has illegal reference to stage object.
if yes, why you want to access stage (that is owned by MAP.swf) from ANI.SWF?

Comment: If I have two SWF files wherein one is the Parent and the other is the Child and If I have to load the Child SWF file to the Parent. Do I have to have only one Document Class? That is for example I should only have this certain Document Class on my Parent SWF. Or should I have only one Document Class which I should use on both the Parent and the Child SWF Files? Thanks.